# how to make a hole area in the bottom corner of the overlay css

Tags: html, css, overlay, cornerradius

I tried to make a hole area in the bottom corner of the overlay like in the image below, but still having trouble.

[image: example of desired final appearance1]

here is an example of the code

```
 <div className="container h-screen bg-overlay fixed z-50 opacity-90 holes"> 
 </div>

.holes::before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      /* Scale */
      width: 50px;
      padding: 10px 0px;
      /* Position */
      position: absolute;
      top: 90%;
      right: 60%;
      z-index: 2;
      /* Border */
      border: solid 80px rgb(255,255,255);
      border-radius: 50%;
      opacity: 0.7;
  }
```

but the code above still doesn't fit because it doesn't make a hole in the lower left corner but makes a new hole with a pseudo class

Comment: Do you want the 'hole' to be a genuine hole, that is to show anything that may be behind (bits of a background image, text etc) or do you want it to be as shown just a bit of white?

Comment: CSS mask (or -webkit-mask on some common browsers) will cut a hole for you.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using pseudo classes. Just an `after` or `before` can be used if you are not expecting it to emit any events.

Do you require a complete circle or a half one?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}

.round {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 50px;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='round'>UPLOAD</span>
</div>
```

EDIT

Added text inside the round

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I want to ask again, what if there is text in the hole in the right corner of the overlay, then the text is not visible (even if I use opacity the text below will be blurry, is there a solution?)

here's an example image:
https://imgur.com/a/qfY8KYh

Comment: I have uploaded the same snippet above with a text inside. As I said, since you require events from this round, I changed the pseudo element to `span` for convenience.

Comment: thank you, but in my case the code structure is like this(https://jsbin.com/qedohit/edit?html,output), so the text is not in the holes/container class, but inside another element

Comment: Ok sure, if the text is in some other wrapper, just add it there and keep the pseudo class for the round

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS mask to cut a hole in an element with a radial-gradient as the mask image. You can put the yellow border around the hole with a background radial gradient at the same place.

This snippet has a container background of magenta so you can see that a genuine 'hole' is cut with whatever is below being shown (though the background radial gradient will cover it with a transparent layer).

Note: view the snippet in Full page

```css
.container {
  background-color: magenta;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.div {
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(circle at 50px 100%, transparent 0, transparent 50px, black 50px, black 100%);
  mask: radial-gradient(circle at 50px 100%, transparent 0, transparent 50px, black 50px, black 100%);
  background-color: skyblue;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50px 100%, transparent 0, transparent 50px, yellow 50px, yellow 53px, transparent 53px, transparent 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thank you for your answer, I have idea now how to implement it