# How i can create edge hole rectangle in css

Tags: css

[image][image]

how can i insert hole near rectangle edge?
can you guide me ? how I can do this!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: i updated please check

Comment: Please show us the code yu have so far. And do you want it to be a 'real' hole, that is, with whatever is behind showing?

Comment: If you want it to be a genuine hole (that can be seen through to show the stuff underneath) use CSS mask - see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645705/how-to-make-a-hole-area-in-the-bottom-corner-of-the-overlay-css/68647927#68647927

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use both `pseudoelements: after and before` to place a circle where you want with border and white backound color and then a square above to "hide" with the same background color half of the circle.

Like this:

```css
div {
  height:200px;
  border:3px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:20px;
}
div:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:26px;
  width:26px;
  border:3px solid #000;
  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  left:-17px;
  top:80px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
div:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:100px;
  width:20px;
  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  left:-23px;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>  
</div>
```

Comment: This isn’t going to work with a non-solid background, or a background whose color may change.